# Cannot get my way around YouTube's api upload thumbnail in python

Tags: python, api, youtube, subprocess

I'm working on uploading videos to YouTube using its api. However, I can't get my way around these errors that are coming from youtubes uploadThumbnail.py file. The errors coming from uploadThumbnail are not identifying the file I'm passing in it. I'm using subprocess to run the uploadThumbnail file and this is where I'm getting the error.

```
def updateThumbnail(imagePath):
    arr = []
    arr = textFile.readLine(r"C:\Users\user1\Desktop\tester\Video-id.txt")
    print(imagePath)
    print(imagePath.replace("\\", "\\\\"))
    (Right below this is the error)
    subprocess.check_output('python Thumbnail.py --file ="'+imagePath.replace("\\", "\\\\")+ '" --video-id=" '+arr[0]+'"')
    print("thumbnail updated!")
```

This is the error that I'm getting.
[image]

Just to give you guys a heads up, I downloaded the code from here -> https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_thumbnail.py

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the space at `--file= "`?

Comment: @Rawing, i cant do that. upload needs a file path